# Missing audio language configuration, unablet to process speech

Tags: raspberry-pi, speech-to-text, node-red, watson

I'm trying out Watson Speech to Text service with Node-RED on Raspberry Pi but getting error:  Missing audio language configuration, unable to process speech.  I'm not seeing a way to specify language within Node-RED node.  What am I missing?

Comment: It is better to show the code you are using currently and clarify what exact error do you see. The more information you provide the faster you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

after you enter the credentials, the text to speech node shows extra configuration input such as voice and audio format that you must configure. (it does not show before because you need the credentials to query the available voices and formats).

you have to enter this info in order to get rid of this error message.